# Problems matching public population and geographic data for France?

Tags: geospatial, census, openstreetmap, france

I am trying to make a chloropleth map of France with the population of each canton.

I have found the [latest census population data from INSEE](http://www.insee.fr/fr/ppp/bases-de-donnees/recensement/populations-legales/). I am now matching this against an [open GeoJSON file of canton boundaries](https://github.com/gregoiredavid/france-geojson) which seems to be based on the openly licensed [GeoFLA](http://professionnels.ign.fr/geofla).

However, there appear to be some disparities (about 300 cantons don't match), and I'm not sure why. For example, the JSON file has an entry for Meaux:

```
{"type":"Feature","id":"7798","properties":{"name":"Meaux","id":"117798"},"geometry":{"type":"Polygon","coordinates":[...]}}
```

But the population file from INSEE contains two different entries for Meaux, neither of which match the one above:

```
7717,Meaux-Nord,51284
7731,Meaux-Sud,36861
```

The boundaries in OpenStreetMap match the GeoJSON file (e.g. Mapit has only one entry for Meaux: http://global.mapit.mysociety.org/area/702351.html )

Does anyone know why the INSEE data doesn't match up?

Comment: Meaux is Arrondissement (~ district) not a canton. Meaux-Nord (North Meaux) and Meaux-Sud (South Meaux) are two of the eight cantons in Meaux.

Comment: @Andrew-OpenGeoCode is there a reason you didn't post your comment as an answer? I don't know much about French geography, but if it's true, it's the best answer.

Comment: Hi @JoeGermuska , don't know why. Too long ago - haha